# How to properly nest IF statement in this formula

Tags: excel

I have this formula:

```
=IF(S56="P",CONCATENATE(LEFT(D58,5),$S$1,"PM"), CONCATENATE(LEFT(D58,5),$S$1,"AM"))
```

If the data it concatenates is null, it's doing an "AM" in cells I don't really want it to. How do I next another if to make it only AM if S56="A"?

I have played with it and moved parenthesis and I am just not good enough with formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

=IF(S56="P",CONCATENATE(LEFT(D58,5),$S$1,"PM"), IF(S56="A",CONCATENATE(LEFT(D58,5),$S$1,"AM"), ""))))